# Сортировка list по двум параметрам

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, сортировка

Помогите пожалуйста отсортировать список по 2 параметрам.
Имеется список:

```
let_list = [('y', 1), ('l', 1), ('m', 4), ('u', 1), ('r', 1), ('a', 4)]
```

тапки в списке нужно отсортировать по второму значению по убыванию, а если второе значение совпадает у нескольких элементов, тогда их нужно отсортировать по первому значению по алфавиту.
После сортировки должно получиться:

```
let_list = [('a', 4), ('m', 4), ('l', 1), ('r', 1), ('u', 1), ('y', 1)]
```

по всей видимости это нужно делать с помощью метода .sorted(), но как правильно - недопонимаю.

Comment: тапки в списке? :)

Comment: Ну, все же поняли)) повеселился слегка

Comment: Первая буква обозначает начальную букву имени, а число - размер тапка )) Я понял, вы пишите программу для автоматической тапкосортировки.

Comment: )))) ну, почти) я учусь в SkillBox и материал подаётся не в лучшем виде, приходится догугливать, а если и там ничего внятного, тогда спрашивать у опытных людей. Но, программу можно предложить на склады торговцев обувью)))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сортировка по ключу - сперва по перевёрнутому второму элементу кортежа, затем по первому элементу:

```
sorted(let_list, key=lambda t: (-t[1], t[0]))
```

Comment: Благодарю, кажется разобрался с вашей помощью